# Как назвать контейнер, который вычисляет значения элементов на лету?

Tags: c++, терминология, именование

У меня есть примерно такой код.

```
// Функциональный объект, для простоты вопроса его смысл
// просто посчитать значение определенным образом.
struct my_functor{
  int operator()(int x) const {
    return (x * x + 17) / 2 + 1;
  }
};

template<class Functor, size_t Size>
struct my_container{
  public:
    decltype(auto) operator[](int n) const {
      return std::visit(_functor, n);
    }
   
    // Также реализованы функции begin, end.

  private:
    Functor _functor;
};

int main(){
  my_container<my_functor, 10> cont;
  
  // Использование operator[].
  std::cout << cont[1] << std::endl;    

  // Использование функций begin, end контейнера.
  for(int value: cont){
    std::cout << value << ", ";
  }
}
```

Если коротко, то реализован контейнер, который вычисляет значение элемента этого контейнера через специальный функциональный объект (так называемый функтор).
То есть в контейнере хранится только размер и функция, через которую вычисляется значение элемента.

И весь вопрос в том, как назвать такой контейнер? Наверное, я не первый, кто до этого додумался, и у такого контейнера (или паттерна) есть какое-нибудь красивое название.

Comment: Ну название-то кому как больше нравится. Но лучше, чтобы название отражало функционал. Тогда когда другие читают код - многое становится понятно даже без комментариев.

Comment: Виртуальный контейнер.

Comment: Ну, например, генератор? :)

Comment: `std::visit(_functor, n)` - опечатка?

Comment: У меня одного ощущение, что после вот таких упражнений с абстакциями появляются банкоматы, которые сначала списывают запрошенную сумму с карточки, а потом сообщают, что требуемое количество денег временно отсутствует и вам надо обратиться в отделение банка? (если что, это **реальный случай** с банкоматом Сбера)

Comment: Почему бы просто не считать его контейнером функторов? )

Comment: называй функции именами покемонов =)

Answer (score 0):

На выбор:

- "view" - так С++20 называет вещи, которые притворяются контейнерами, например [`std::views::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/iota_view).
- "range" - так С++20 называет и views и контейнеры вместе.

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее, что именно из range имеет схожее поведение?

Comment: @AntonMitrokhin Я имею в виду не хедер ranges, а конкретно концепт [`std::ranges::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range) - он возвращает true для контейнеров и для типов вроде вашего.